# Is this question structure correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I am doubting if this question is correctly written.

> 10 to the power of what the number results in 100?

If this were not a valid question, how would I have to ask it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An English-speaking mathematician would probably say this instead:

> What is the [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) (base 10) of 100?

This is usually written "log<sub>10</sub> 100" in mathematical typography.

If you really don't want to use the word "logarithm," you could ask:

> - 10 to the power of what number equals 100? (Note there is no article before "number, and "equals" is more idiomatic than "results in.")
> - To what power do you have to raise 10 to get 100?

Comment: Thank you for answering and giving more idiomatic ways to say this